# Change Datetime to ddmmyy in SAS

Tags: datetime, sas

I want to change a date variable from DateTime (e.g. 11NOV17:06:36:00) to show 11/11/17. The informat is ANYDTDTM40 and type is numeric. The data sheet contains some 3600 observations and they all need to be changed. I have tried multiple combinations without luck - they all just give either "********" or "." as date results.

I thought this would be a simple task but it has taken me hours and I still can't figure it out. I am fairly new in SAS so please be descriptive when answering.

Hope you can help!
Thanks

Comment: Why show dates in DMY order? That will confuse half of your audience.  There is a format (E8601DN10.) that will display datetime values (number of seconds) in YMD order and with that order no one will confuse the tenth of December for October twelfth.

Comment: HW? https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Help-Formatting-Date-and-Keeping-only-recent-entries/m-p/797086

Comment: @Tom I want to use DMY order because this is the regular way I normally use it and it is normally displayed like this in Denmark. So MDY would really just confuse myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  date = datepart(datetime_variable) ; /* take date component of the datetime */
  format date ddmmyy10. ; /* format to ddmmyy10. */
run ;
```

Comment: So when doing this, it doesn't change any of the written dates. I did like this:                   
  data kultur3 ;  
  set kultur2 ;  
  SAMPLE_D = datepart(datetime_variable) ;  
  format SAMPLE_D ddmmyy10. ;  
run ;   And I get the following in the log:   NOTE: Variable datetime_variable is uninitialized. 
  NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.  
Each place is given by: (Number of times) at (Line):(Column)  3508 at 75:10.  I only get dots as a result in SAMPLE_D.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scene, so called dates as well as datetimes are just double precision real numbers.
However, if you assign a format `date9.` to a variable and you print it, SAS will print the date of being that many days after 1jan1960.
Likewise, if you assign a format `datetime19.` to a variable and you print it date and time of that many seconds after the start of 1jan1960.

Sas has a function that calculates the days from the seconds: `myDate = datepart(myDateTime);`, but don't forget to format your variable too `format myDate date9.;`

Also note that all formats for numerics look like `<type>length.<decimas>`, in which

- `<type>` can for instance be `date` or `percent`,
- `length`, the only obligatory part, is the maximal length in characters and
- `<decimals>` is the number of decimals for the fractions

So a numeric with format `1.` will be displayed as `1`, `2`, ... or `9`. If it is negative too large to display as 1 digit, it will display as an overflow: `#`

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying that. What I really just want is to delete the seconds form the dates and write the date different.

Comment: It this site, wa express our thanks by upvoting answers :) This also helps readers finding relevant answers easyer

Answer (score 0):

Okay so update: This is what worked for me:
SAMPLE_D is my date variable that is showing Datetime "11NOV17:06:36:00", and I want it without hours and seconds.

```
data want;
set have;
SAMPLE_D = datepart(SAMPLE_D);
format SAMPLE_D ddmmyy10.; 
run;
```

Things are now showing as 11/11/2017. I can't believe I didn't find it previously. Thanks a lot